# OnPointerDown for Overlapping 3D Objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two identical 3D objects in my scene. Both of them have a boolean property: **isSelected**. For one of the objects, isSelected is true. For the other - isSelected is false.

Both objects have a script attached, which implements the IPointerDownHandler interface.

At some point in the game, both 3D objects have the same coordinates (absolutely the same coordinates, the objects overlap each other). If I click an object with my mouse, is there a way for me to predict for which object the OnPointerDown event will been triggered? I only want the OnPointerDown event to trigger for the object with isSelected == true.

Is there any way to achieve this? Should I use raycasts? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I will not make an answer with this as this is just a suggestion. When OnPointerDown  event is triggerd you check is isSelected is true, if not you fire a ray from current touch/mouse position and checking all collider's components with IPointerDownHandler implemented and check if any of them has isSelected set to true. If yes you trigger the event manually.

Comment: Just as Jerry says - it's that easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems so easy I might misunderstand you!

```
if (!isSelected) return;
.. your handling code ..
```

Another idea is, in Unity you should really use components a lot, they are a natural part of things.  Don't forget each of your c# scripts is indeed a "component".

Google "Unity3d disable a component" for a [basic tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/enabling-disabling-components)

```
yourComponent.enabled = false;
```

You say

> I only want the OnPointerDown event to trigger for the object with isSelected == true.

Thus, perhaps just *turn off that whole component* with the boolean.

Another cool idea is this: ***turn off the collider*** with the boolean.

```
Collider c = GetComponent<Collider>();
c.enabled = false;
```

Then you truly won't get the event, you see?

Regarding your separate question

> there a way for me to predict for which object the OnPointerDown event will been triggered

Since you're talking 3D objects,

1) If one is *closer to the camera*, that's the one

2) If they are in truly identical 3D positions, which should never happen: No, there's absolutely no way to tell, it's "random".

Comment: Thanks, @Joe Blow. I'm trying the "turning off the collider" approach for now, works like a charm.

Comment: Excellent, that's definitely a key technique to familiarize yourself with, Enjoy!